# When using MySqlSessionProvider, what deletes expired sessions?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, session-state

Everything I know about Asp.Net Session Providers I know from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx). However, at work we're using the MySql Session Provider and I'm confused about one detail: Session Expiration.

On that MSDN page, it says:

> The ASPState database includes a SQL Server Agent job that
>   periodically (by default, every 60 seconds) calls the stored procedure
>   DeleteExpiredSessions to remove expired sessions.

I have a few problems with this. We're using MySql so there is no SQL Server Agent to do this. Also, there doesn't appear to be any Routines at all for our instance of the database. For the record, we do have `autogenerateschema="true"` so if it used Routines, I'd imagine it would have made them.

Can somebody shed some light on the MySql specifics of the Session State Store and Session Expiration?

Comment: Are your expired sessions actually being deleted?  Or are there just lots of old sessions in the MySql table?

Comment: It's working as expected. Expired sessions are being deleted at proper times.

Comment: My best guess is that IIS is somehow calling the MySqlSessionProvider but I don't have anyway to test that.

Comment: See the MSDN article on [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587(v=vs.100).aspx), under the heading "*Deleting expired session-store data*". If you have the code for the MySqlSessionProvider, perhaps you can start looking in those places.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I do not have the code. We're using `MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore` from the MySql.Web.dll.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code, it looks like the MySqlSessionStateStore class takes care of it by running a timer that clears expired sessions.